# Vertical alignment in \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I am using `\multirow` to produce a table. I would like the first row to be vertically aligned.
As you see, the first column of the first row ("Legislature") is not aligned with the rest of the row. Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

The code is

```
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{4}*{Legislature} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PMBs per legislator} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
    & {Mean} & {Sd} & {Min} & {Max} 
    & {Total PMBs} & {PMBs per day} \\
    \midrule
    13th legislature & 10.24 & 13.96 & 0 & 151 & 6450 & 3.49 \\
    14th legislature & 9.04 & 14.16 & 0 & 170 & 5578  & 3.11 \\
    15th legislature & 5.04 & 8.01 & 0 & 71 & 3217 & 4.40  \\
    16th legislature & 7.72 & 11.57 & 0 & 108 & 5258 & 2.94 \\
    17th legislature & 6 .63 & 9.11 & 0 & 96 & 4384 & 2.38  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Leave out `\multirow{4}*{Legislature}` and put `Legislature` before `& {Mean}`.

Answer (score 5):

To solve your problem, just leave out `\multirow{4}*{Legislature}` and put `Legislature` before `& {Mean}`.

I would also like to suggest using `siunitx` for the alignment of your numbers.

And don't repeat `legislature` at every row when you already have it in the column header.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l
                *2{S[table-format=2.2]}
                S[table-format=1]
                S[table-format=3]
                S[table-format=4]
                S[table-format=1.2]}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PMBs per legislator} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
    Legislature & {Mean} & {Sd} & {Min} & {Max} 
    & {Total PMBs} & {PMBs per day} \\
    \midrule
    13th & 10.24 & 13.96 & 0 & 151 & 6450 & 3.49 \\
    14th & 9.04 & 14.16 & 0 & 170 & 5578  & 3.11 \\
    15th & 5.04 & 8.01 & 0 & 71 & 3217 & 4.40  \\
    16th & 7.72 & 11.57 & 0 & 108 & 5258 & 2.94 \\
    17th & 6 .63 & 9.11 & 0 & 96 & 4384 & 2.38  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]